# I am able to successfully scrape through multiple websites using requests/callbacks. However, when I write to a csv, I am getting duplicate items

Tags: python, scrapy

My code does the following:

1. Parse through original website: Finviz.com, and scrape a few items such as P/E, etc.
2. Request callbacks and parse through two separate urls in Yahoo finance and extract some more information.
3. Return the requested items back into one clean dictionary value containing the finviz information AND yahoo information.

I seem to have successfully done so. However, I am having trouble with the output. The output is writing BOTH the finviz information, like the P/E, marketcap, AND outputs the newly accessed information, which is now the collective finviz + yahoo (<- I only want the latter). I don't know why it's outputting both, it causes a lot of duplicates in my csv file.

```
class FinvizSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "finviz"
    allowed_domains = ["finviz.com", "finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_smallover&ft=4&c=0,1,2,6,7,10,11,13,14,45,65"]

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('r=\d+'),restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="tab-link"]')
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_items(response)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        trs = hxs.select('//table[@bgcolor="#d3d3d3"]/tr');
        items = []
        for tr in trs[1:len(trs)]:
            item = StockfundamentalsItem()
            item['ticker'] = tr.select('td[2]/a/text()').extract()
            item ["marketcap"] = tr.select("td[4]//text()").extract()
            item ["pEarnings"] = tr.select("td[5]//text()").extract()
            item ["pSales"] = tr.select("td[6]//text()").extract()
            item ["pBook"] = tr.select("td[7]//text()").extract()
            item ["pFCF"] = tr.select("td[8]//text()").extract()
            item ["Div"] = tr.select("td[9]//text()").extract()


            newurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" + item['ticker'][0] + "+Key+Statistics"
            newurl2 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s="+ item['ticker'][0] + "&ql=1"


            yield Request(newurl, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.LinkParse)
            yield Request(newurl2, meta={'item': item}, callback = self.LinkParse2)

            items.append(item)
        return items



    def LinkParse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        enterprise = hxs.select('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//tr[9]/td[2]/text()').extract()
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Enterprise'] = [enterprise[0]] 
        return item


    def LinkParse2(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        stockpurchases = hxs.select('//table[@class="yfnc_tabledata1"]//tr[23]')
        runningtot = 0 

        tds = (stockpurchases.select("./td/text()")).extract()
        for elements in tds[1:]:
            val = float(elements.strip().replace('-','0').replace(',','').replace('(','-').replace(')',''))
            runningtot = runningtot + val

        item = response.meta['item']

        item['BBY'] = [runningtot] 

        return item
```

For example my output looks something like this (Notice the pre-yahoo information, and post-yahoo information):

```
pFCF,pBook,pEarnings,BBY,Enterprise,marketcap,Div,ticker,pSales
14.44,3.24,33.45,,10.66,13.70B,0.98%,A,2.17
14.44,3.24,33.45,17000,10.66,13.70B,0.98%,A,2.17
.
.
.
```

Not even in that order. It's pretty scrambled (which I don't mind) I just don't want the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Upon messing around, I found the solution was to post a request inside my 2nd request.

Pretty much:

```
class FinvizSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "finviz"
    allowed_domains = ["finviz.com", "finance.yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&f=cap_smallover&ft=4&c=0,1,2,6,7,10,11,13,14,45,65"]

    rules = (Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('r=\d+'),restrict_xpaths='//a[@class="tab-link"]')
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        return self.parse_items(response)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        trs = hxs.select('//table[@bgcolor="#d3d3d3"]/tr');
        items = []
        for tr in trs[1:len(trs)]:
            item = StockfundamentalsItem()
            item['ticker'] = tr.select('td[2]/a/text()').extract()
            item ["marketcap"] = tr.select("td[4]//text()").extract()
            item ["pEarnings"] = tr.select("td[5]//text()").extract()
            item ["pSales"] = tr.select("td[6]//text()").extract()
            item ["pBook"] = tr.select("td[7]//text()").extract()
            item ["pFCF"] = tr.select("td[8]//text()").extract()
            item ["Div"] = tr.select("td[9]//text()").extract()


            newurl = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=" + item['ticker'][0] + "+Key+Statistics"



            yield Request(newurl, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.LinkParse)


            items.append(item)
        return items



    def LinkParse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        enterprise = hxs.select('//table[@class="yfnc_datamodoutline1"]//tr[9]/td[2]/text()').extract()
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Enterprise'] = [enterprise[0]] 
        newurl2 = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cf?s="+ item['ticker'][0] + "&ql=1"
        yield Request(newurl2, meta={'item': item}, callback = self.LinkParse2)
        return


    def LinkParse2(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        stockpurchases = hxs.select('//table[@class="yfnc_tabledata1"]//tr[23]')
        runningtot = 0 

        tds = (stockpurchases.select("./td/text()")).extract()
        for elements in tds[1:]:
            val = float(elements.strip().replace('-','0').replace(',','').replace('(','-').replace(')',''))
            runningtot = runningtot + val

        item = response.meta['item']

        item['BBY'] = [runningtot] 

        return item
```

However, this doesn't seem like the proper way to go about this problem... Is there a way to perform multiple requests properly?

Comment: Actually this is a proper way. You can also try Scrapy Inline Requests https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests